# can't understand bash script : $@ etc

Tags: bash

I'm looking at this bash script and can't understand.
I can understand $@ is all the positional parameters(arguments from shell) and #array[@] means the number of parameters. (let alone its queer syntax..). The rest I don't understand..

```
#/bin/bash

array=( $@ )
len=${#array[@]}
EXTRA_ARGS=${array[@]:2:$len}
EXTRA_ARGS_SLUG=${EXTRA_ARGS// /_}
```

EDIT : oh, I realized, the third line is taking some range of parameters from the array, and the last line is doing concatenating all the parameters with '_'.

Comment: Everything is in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html). Start with the _6.7 Arrays_ section.

Comment: also, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073

Comment: http://explainshell.com/ is your friend here. EDIT: OK, not here. That stupid side does not seem to understand arrays & parameter expansion.

Comment: On another note, you should really use quotes around parameter expansion e.g. `"$@"` instead of `$@` Also, I think you want to use `EXTRA_ARGS_SLUG=("${EXTRA_ARGS[@]// /_}")` instead of `EXTRA_ARGS_SLUG=${EXTRA_ARGS// /_}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXTRA_ARGS_SLUG=${EXTRA_ARGS// /_}

replaces space /  /   by underscore /_

Answer (score 0):

The last two are subclasses of parameter expansion in `bash`.

---

`${array[@]:2:$len}` is array slicing pattern. The syntax is:

```
${parameter:offset:length}
```

So it will output array element starting from index 2 to whatever length the variable `$len` contains.

---

`${EXTRA_ARGS// /_}` is replacement pattern.  The syntax is:

```
${parameter//pattern/replacement}
```

All spaces in parameter `EXTRA_ARGS` are replaced with `_`.

To replace only the first occurrence, the pattern `${EXTRA_ARGS/ /_}` would be used.

Answer (score 0):

This code is incorrect, because it ignores the reason to use `$@`: to protect whitespace that occurs *in* arguments. You should always quote `$@`. By assigning to `EXTRA_ARGS`, you lose the ability to distinguish between spaces that are part of an argument, and spaces that separate arguments.

```
array=( "$@" )
EXTRA_ARGS=( "${array[@]:2:$len}" )
OLD_IFS=$IFS; IFS=_; EXTRA_ARGS_SLUG=${EXTRA_ARGS[*]}; IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

You don't actually need the array; you can work directly with `$@`:

```
EXTRA_ARGS=( "${@:3:$len}" )  # positional parameters are numbered from 1, though
```